# PHP password validate number 12345 or abcde using regex

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords, rule

For my rule here I want to validate a password field that contains at least 5 characters long but those must not be abcde or 12345 or reverse. How can I? Here I don't want to force users to enter at least 1 letter 1 number or a symbols in combination.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Why does it have to be done using regex? You can check for known bad values in PHP code.

Comment: Have you already tried something? Because that looks to me like something that is easy to solve? Anyway, if it isn't, give us some code about your previous attempts and why you didn't like the results of your code. So it's easier for us to give you feedback on your own code.

Comment: Here I didn't mean only 12345, but 123456789 or abcde, but abcdefg something like this

Comment: Just make a dictionary with the most common passwords, and test against this dictionary. There are not so many realistic combinations with 123 1234 12345 to test. With a dictionary you can also test combinations like `qwert` or `password`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$uppercase = preg_match('@[A-Z]@', $password);
$lowercase = preg_match('@[a-z]@', $password);
$number    = preg_match('@[0-9]@', $password);

if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || strlen($password) < 8) {
  // tell the user something went wrong
}
```

documentation: http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match.php

source: [Regex for password PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141125/regex-for-password-php)