# Make a validation with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

You can help me with this problem that I have, I would like to validate a password with specific requirements, which are:
- It must contain a number, a capital letter and a special character. It must also be between 8 and 12 characters. Make the following pattern:

```
$special_chars = '!@#$%^&*()';
$pattern = "/[A-Z0-9{$special_chars}]{8,12}/";
$password = '$dsd%FG23X';
preg_match($pattern, $password, $matches);
```

But it does not work and I need to know what the correct pattern would be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for password PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8141125/1255289)

Comment: Also, see [this](https://ideone.com/AysFCv)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the positive look-ahead. I've used [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to build the expression. First we check the required characters, then we check for the length. Here's what I came up with:

```
$special_chars = '!@#$%^&*(),.`';
$pattern = '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[' . $special_chars . ']).*$/';

$password = '$dsd%FG23X';
preg_match($pattern, $password, $matches);

$password_validated = false;

if (strlen($password) >= 8 && strlen($password) < 50)
{
    if ( ! empty($matches)) {
        $password_validated = true;
    }
}

var_dump($password_validated);
```

Returns:

```
bool(true)
```

By the way, it's good to have a minimum password length, but it is a bad idea to have such a short maximum. You should allow the users the ability to have more complex characters, consider allowing something generous, like 50 characters. I generate my passwords with [KeePass](https://keepass.info/) and they are usually at least 20 characters long.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But this will return a value for a string that is entirely lowercase.

Comment: Looks like you have added the characters `[ | ] \ _ \`` too. Take a look at the ASCII table to see what `A-z` contains.

Comment: The problem is that if you remove the numbers equal returns the string. It is problematic, since I want a pattern that requires a number, a capital letter and a special character.

Comment: @MarcosDavidHuarangaOrtega I've edited my answer, try now.

Comment: You can't check the string length if you allow any number of characters before your lookahead `(?=.{8,12})`. Also, variables aren't interpolated between single quotes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for the feedback, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Now your code works. But the idea of my previous comment was to remove the useless `.*` before `(?=.{8,12})`, not the lookahead itself.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks so much for your feedback, I've edit my answer with new changes.