# Regex to validate passwords with characters restrictions

Tags: regex, passwords

I need to validate a password with these rules:

- 6 to 20 characters
- Must contain at least one digit;
- Must contain at least one letter (case insensitive);
- Can contain the following characters: ! @ # $ % & *

The following expression matches all but the last requirement. What can I do with the last one?

`((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-z]).{6,20})`

Comment: Not a regex expert, but couldn't you just add a `[!@#\$%&\*]?` too it?

Comment: Which language Java, javascript....??

Comment: Do you mean "can contain the following characters in addition to letters and numbers?"

Comment: I think there's an implicit "must not contain characters other than alphanumerics and the specific punctuation (from the fourth rule)."  If not, this should be even easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP regular expression for strong password validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637896/php-regular-expression-for-strong-password-validation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I have this right, but since your last requirement is "***Can*** contain the following characters: !@#$%&*" I am assuming that other special characters are not allowed.  In other words, the only allowed characters are letters, digits, and the special characters !@#$%&*.

If this is the correct interpretation, the following regex should work:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]{6,20})$
```

Note that I changed your character class `[A-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`, because `[A-z]` will also include the following characters: [\]^_`

I also added beginning and end of string anchors to make sure you don't get a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

Regex could be:-

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]{6,20}$
```

How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844359/password-regex-with-min-6-chars-at-least-one-letter-and-one-number-and-may-cont) in Javascript:-

```
function checkPwd(str) {
    if (str.length < 6) {
        return("too_short");
    } else if (str.length > 20) {
        return("too_long");
    } else if (str.search(/\d/) == -1) {
        return("no_num");
    } else if (str.search(/[a-zA-Z]/) == -1) {
        return("no_letter");
    } else if (str.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+]/) != -1) {
        return("bad_char");
    }
    return("ok");
}
```

Also check out [this](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]{6,20}$
```