# REGEX a-z 0-9 but not only numbers

Tags: java, regex

Trying to match only strings 10-30 characters long with only a-z and 0-9 (but not  only numbers) in the string.  Seems to work Except when the string starts with a number then it fails.
Not sure about the \D which should fix the not only numbers

```
static final Pattern UNIQUE_ID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\D[A-Za-z0-9_-]{10,30}$");
UNIQUE_ID_PATTERN.matcher("1eeeeeeeee333e").matches(); // Does not work
UNIQUE_ID_PATTERN.matcher("eeeeeeeee333e").matches(); // Works
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\D` shorthand class means `any non-digit symbol`. You should remove it from the pattern (so that it becomes `"^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{10,30}$"`) for the `matches` to return true, as `1` is a digit in `1eeeeeeeee333e`.

If you want to place a restriction (the string cannot consist of only digits) use an anchored look-ahead:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)[A-Za-z0-9_-]{10,30}$
```

Here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX4gG8/3)

Or, a shortened version with `i` modifier making the pattern case-insensitive:

```
(?i)^(?![0-9]+$)[A-Z0-9_-]{10,30}$
```

Comment: I updated the answer with a version to disallow digit-only strings.

Comment: Nice. +1 for the negative look ahead.

Comment: I suggest that you read [*Various Uses for Lookarounds* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#uses). It is quite useful.

Comment: it does not work for me.

Comment: @SalahAdDin Then your issue is different from the OP.

Comment: the next answer worked for me.

Comment: @SalahAdDin The OP problem is *not matching a string that only contains digits*. The [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32267206/3832970) shows how to match a string that *must contain at least one ASCII letter*, and is a solution, too, but uses different logic.

Answer (score 2):

**Another way:** `^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z])+)([a-zA-Z\d]{10,30})$`  ***update***

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yX4gG8/5)**

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637896/php-regular-expression-for-strong-password-validation)

Comment: This is not JavaScript, see the post tags. In Java, you cannot use regex delimiters as in JavaScript or PHP.