# i want some special character in password

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation

i wrote

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'password',
    'password',
    'required|min_length[4]|max_length[8]|regex_match[/^[a-z0-9]+$/]'
);
```

but I want  :
 Password must
contain exactly 2
special characters and
2 uppercase letters

how to write ?

Comment: Why? https://xkcd.com/936/ (not to mention only 4-8 characters is always going to be relatively weak)

Comment: other than the regular password string ? min_length[4] is not very protective

Comment: yes sir but this is task...

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637896/php-regular-expression-for-strong-password-validation

Answer (score 3):

You can use callback function:
Example:

```
public function password_check($str)
{
   if (preg_match('#[\W]{2}#', $str) && preg_match('#[A-Z]{2}#', $str)) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

And Validation Part:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[passconf]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|callback_password_check');
```

Comment: he wants 2 special characters not numbers you have taken [0-9]

Comment: \w matches a word character. not special character

Comment: \w     Any word character (letter, number, underscore)

Comment: \W     Any non-word character check here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a special character regularly expression to u:

```
/[\'.,:;*?~`!@#$%^&+=)(<>{}]|\]|\[|\/|\\\|\"|\|/
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, sir but I want exactly 2 special characters and 2 uppercase letters that's why I am confuse